# mysql: перезаписать строку, если она существует

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

Есть таблица `user` с полями `id`, `surname`, `username`. 
Данные прилетают в бд в формате json, когда пользователь нажмет на кнопку.

```
[
 { id: '1',
    surname: 'Пупкин',
    username: 'Иван'
 }, 
{ id: '2',
    surname: 'Иванова',
    username: 'Маша'
 }
]
```

Задача:

1. если прилетевшего `id` нет, необходимо записать данные в таблицу;
2. если прилетевший `id` есть, необходимо перезаписать данные (`id` остается прежним, все остальные данные меняются)

```
connect.query('INSERT INTO user SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id', data, 
   function(err, result) {
       if (err) throw err;
});
```

Мой запрос инсертит новые данные, но не меняет уже существующие. Как сделать по человечески?

Comment: Раз надо обновить поля surname и username так и укажите в update вместо id=id (который ничего не делает меняя id сам на себя) то что вам нужно (`insert .... key update surname=values(surname), username=values(username)`)

Answer (score 1):

Директива `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` срабатывает если у вас уже есть какое-то значение в БД по уникальному ключу. Таким ключом может быть поле `id`, тогда его нужно указать в списке полей:

```
INSERT INTO user SET id = 2, ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

Если поле id не объявлено уникальным, [это следует сделать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255304/how-add-unique-key-to-existing-table-with-non-uniques-rows).

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD UNIQUE (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE INTO `user`
SET id = @id, surname = @surname, username = @username;
```

Comment: Если у вас есть внешние ключи, то `REPLACE` может наделать дел, удалив все связанные записи. Лучше обходить стороной.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае вы можете использовать либо REPLACE, либо INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, которые в итоге дадут одинаковый результат. Умные теоретики пишут, что INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE предпочтительнее (я не понял почему).
Как правильно заметил @sanmai оба метода сработают, если у вас есть уникальные ключи. В вашем случае нужно выполнить команду

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD UNIQUE "index" (id);
```

## REPLACE:

```
REPLACE INTO user 
(id, surname, username)
VALUES
(1, "Пупкин", "Ваня");
```

## INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO user
(id, surname, username)
VALUES 
(1, "Пупкин", "Иван")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
surname ="Пупкин",
username="Иван";
```

В обоих случаях данные будут обновлены и и не появится дубликата.
Источник: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/#using-replace